# javascript executing function after full image load

Tags: javascript, image, callback, load

I have the following line of javascritp `$("#hero_image img").attr('src', src);` to change an image. The following lines then do whatever they do based on the images new width which I was calling through `$("#hero_image img").width();`.

However, how do I ensure that this image has fully loaded before getting the width, otherwise I will be returned with the old width? Setting a timeout isn't reliable enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the width in the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event handler which fires after it's fully loaded, like this:

```
$("#hero_image img").load(function() {
  alert($(this).width());
}).attr('src', src);
```

If you're doing this and re-using the image, either bind the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler once, of you need different behavior each time use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so it doesn't keep *adding* an `onload` event handler:

```
$("#hero_image img").one('load', function() {
  alert($(this).width());
}).attr('src', src);
```

Comment: Why to use `one` instead of `on`?

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan so the handler only executes once, `.one()` has a very specific purpose - run then unbind.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){ // document ready
    $('#hero_image img').bind('load', function(){ // image ready
        // do stuff here
    });
});
```