# Fire event if image is finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript executing function after full image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100252/javascript-executing-function-after-full-image-load)

Im using JQuery to programmatically change the html `img`:

```
$('#myimage').attr('src', 'url-of-image');
```

That may take some time depending on the `url-of-image`.

How can we add an event that will trigger if the new image was loaded successfully?

Comment: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded, `load` doesn't work consistently in IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#myimage').attr('src', 'url-of-image').load(function() {
   // after load
});
```

Edit: working example http://jsfiddle.net/yaSWM/

Edit 2: this works fine on all major browsers.

Comment: personally I would set the event handler before setting the source

Comment: It doesn't matter much because interpreting is way faster than fetching the URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myimage').attr('src', 'url-of-image').on('load', function(){
    //image loaded
});
```

Comment: personally I would set the event handler before setting the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load` event as described in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$('#myimage').load(function() {
  //do whatever
}
```