# How to check if changes to innerHTML have completely loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm changing the content of a div via javascript using `myDiv.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText`. `xmlHttp.responseText` might contain a few images which will be loaded after the div's innerHTML has been changed.

Is there any event which is fired on the div, document or window after those images have completed loading ie after innerHTML of an element has completely loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript executing function after full image load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100252/javascript-executing-function-after-full-image-load)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because it refers to change of attribute on a preexisting element. Over here new html content is being included inside a div.

Comment: I'd say you're both right. The question is not a duplicate of this one, but the answer given should still actually be useful to you; you'll want to query for all images and add a load event to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I went through your question several times again and I came up with this process :

http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/oyv0f7ns/

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">Click Me</div>
<div id="myDiv2">Watch</div>
```

I used two `div` so that you could observe the loading of differents images.

**JS (No JQuery)**

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var myDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDiv2");

var myWatcher = 0;

myDiv.onclick = function () {

    var myImage = "<img id='myImage' src='http://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/sass-less.png' style='max-width: 150px;' />";

    var myImage2 = "<img id='myImage2' src='http://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/devices.png' style='max-width: 150px;'  />";

    myDiv.innerHTML = myImage;
    myDiv2.innerHTML = myImage2;

    // Most important part. Get all the img tags AFTER div was modified.
    var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    // Check if each img is loaded. Second img might be loaded before first.
    for (var i = 0; i < myImg.length; i++) {

        myImg[i].onload = function () {
            myWatcher++;

            if (myWatcher == myImg.length) {
                alert("All is loaded.");
                // Might want to call a function for anything you might want to do.
            }
        };
    }
};
```

In my example, I used a `click event` but the most important part is, of course, the capture of all your `img` element right after you modify your DOM.

The for loop allow the add an eventListener (here : `onload`) on each `img` so that you know when it's loaded.

I have a counter which is incremented when an `img` is loaded. When he is equal to `myImg.length` it means all's good.

**PS (Edit) :** Haven't tested on other browsers (just Chrome).

Hope it might help you, even by a little.

Comment: This solves most of my problems so I'll mark it as my answer. But what about images that are specified in the element's stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay : Busy WE ^^". Anyway. I still tried looking at image in element stylesheet since I hadn't though about it when I wrote my answer but so far, I can't find anything. I think this problem deserve a complete question of its own.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to search though `responseText` for `<img>` and add `onload="function()"`.  You could do that with `responseText.replace(/<img/g,"<img onload=\"function\"")`.

As the comments on the question suggested, another way would be to loop through `myDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")` and add an event listener to the `"load"` event for each one.

Answer (score -1):

There is an event, which is fired after the images are completely loaded. So in your ajax request, you can set up an event listener:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      // readyState==4 means "request finished and response is ready"
      // status==200 means "everything transferred correctly"

    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.